# JavaScript innerHTML not loading data

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get the values that were entered by the user from the window prompts, and let them display in paragraph tags on by html page. I thought using `document.getElementById("idName").innerHTML` would work, but it doesn't show the values that were entered by the user.

Here is the code I have on my JavaScript page. I have called the methods that need to execute on the page. :

```
var players = [];
var numberOfMoves = 0;
var currentPlayer = 0;

getPlayerNames(); //Get player names
setPlayerInformation(); //Set the names of the players in paragraph tags with id playerOneInformation and playerTwoInformation

function getPlayerNames()
{
    players[0] = window.prompt("Please Enter Player 1: ", "");
    players[1] = window.prompt("Please Enter Player 2: ", "");
}

function setPlayerInformation()
{
    document.getElementById("playerOneInformation").innerHTML = players[0];
    document.getElementById("playerTwoInformation").innerHTML = players[1];
}
```

Comment: You are probably calling the method before the data loads in the elements. You need to call `setPlayerInformation()` after the user enters the data.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w8csee4k/1/ works fine here!

Comment: Not answering the question, but if the user should only be able to insert text then you can better use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`. `innerHTML` treats the user input as html, and thus can mess up your document. `textContent` doesn't have that problem.